# Can a semiconductor have net charge?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, charge, semiconductor-physics

If a semiconductor has net charge, the extra electrons should be in the conduction band making semiconductor conductive.
However in the case of field effect transistor, It is not conductive until the applied gate voltage above the threshold.
What did I miss?

Comment: Pretty unclear what your are envisioning - a diagram would help. By applying a voltage, you are no longer in equilibrium.

Comment: Just about anything can have a net charge, this includes semiconductors. I cant follow your scenario well enough to tell if thats whats happening in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I simplified my question.